# Visual Studio 2008 Install Using an ISO

Tags: visual-studio, installation

I need to install Visual Studio 2008 Professional and business constraints are keeping me from install 2010.  I only found the ISO from Microsoft. What's the easiest way to install this?

Comment: There are many free ISO mounting utilities.  I use Virtual CloneDrive from Slysoft.  It works well enough for me - I'm sure many others work just as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .iso is meant to let you to burn a DVD.  Having a backup copy is wise, handy to have when your machine implodes.  Or you could use a utility that allows you to mount the .iso as though it is a drive.  I've had good luck with PowerIso, there are many others.

Answer (score 1):

Burn the ISO to CD/DVD (whichever is appropriate) or use an ISO mounting utility. You can also use something like ISO Buster to extract the contents to a folder tree on your hard disk.